# How to prevent storyboard from running every target in my application?

Tags: ios, xcode, ibdesignable

I have an Xcode project which has several targets, among which a shared target which has a dependency dedicated to increasing the build number when archiving.

Whenever I edit my `Storyboard`s, the build number increases, which means the archiving target is run even though it is NOT the active target.

I've noticed that I get warnings on my `IBDesignable` elements, which according to another answer comes from one of my test targets not currently compiling properly, which confirms my thinking that Storyboard go and compile targets they should not, imho. These are coded in Swift, if it matters.

Henceforth, how do I make sure the storyboard compilation only involves the currently active target?